# Add missing row with Macro/Excel or Matlab

Tags: excel, vba, matlab

I am really struggling with the simple task to write a Code to fill missing data in a measurement file. I've never coded before so it is quite difficult.

---

**Problem description:**

I have uploaded a picture with an example of the problem.

The source format is a .csv file with two columns, a timestamp (hh:mm:ss) and a value for each timestamp. 
I created the row 'time value' in excel, which is displaying the timestamp as a number. (minute 1 = 1/1440 to minute 59 = 1439/1440). 
In column D, I put the difference between two timesteps, which should be around 0.007 for a 1-minute step.

However, the problem is that some minutes are missing in the data throughout the column, sometimes only one minute and sometimes multiple.

---

**Required Code**

So what I need would be a Matlab Code, for instance, that would go through the timestamps or time values and identify missing minutes and write the values of its previous minute.

For example. Minute 6 missing? --> Write row for minute 6 and give it the value of minute 5.

I hope my problem is clear, otherwise, I am happy to explain more details.

--

Cheers

Alison :)

PS: The multiple files each have hundreds of thousands of data. That's why I would need an automated code :)

**PICTURE:**

[image: Problem description - Missing rows]

Comment: Why do you say `timestamp can't be read by Matlab`?  MATLAB should have no problem reading it.

Comment: Hey Phil, I meant that I could not do mathematical operations with the time stamp in order to find missing time steps. 
Thank you for helping. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do stuff like this :

```
Sub test()
lastrow = Worksheets("Inactive").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 3 To lastrow
If Format(TimeValue(CDate(Cells(i, 1).Value)) - TimeValue(CDate(Cells(i - 1, 1).Value)), "hh:mm:ss") > "00:01:00" Then
Rows(i).Insert
Cells(i, 1).Value = Format(TimeValue(CDate(Cells(i - 1, 1).Value) + "00:01:00"), "hh:mm:ss")
Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i - 1, 2).Value
End If
Next
End Sub
```

**before**

[image]

**Output AFTER**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it with this macro and see how this turns out. :)

Comment: @Alison2622 you are welcome, don’t hesitate to leave me feedbacks even if it works

Comment: Thank you very much again! This helped me a lot

Comment: @Alison2622 can you accept this answer then please ?